# How can i easily convert a rgb color value into a hex color value?

Tags: image, perl, colors, imagemagick, color-scheme

I am using the perl API of ImageMagick. I receive color values in rgb scheme but need to get hex values in order to use it on websites (example `#FFA8F5`).

**How can i easily convert a rgb color value into a hex color value?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `printf` or `sprintf` with `%x` format,

```
my ($r,$g,$b) = (12,102,250);
printf("#%02x%02x%02x",$r,$g,$b);
```

**output:**

```
#0c66fa
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it:

```
my @rgb     = (102, 205, 0);
my $hex_rgb = sprintf "#%02X%02X%02X", @rgb;
```

Comment: No. It is the same. It just assigns to a string instead of printing.

Answer (score 2):

```
function colorToHex(color) {
    if (color.substr(0, 1) === '#') {
        return color;
    }
    var digits = /(.*?)rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/.exec(color),

        red = parseInt(digits[2], 10),
        green = parseInt(digits[3], 10),
        blue = parseInt(digits[4], 10),

        rgb = blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16);
    return digits[1] + '#' + rgb.toString(16);
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/YSbwd/)